# How to Serializable xml to class

Tags: c#, xml

I got the below XML that I am trying to make a Serializable class to read

```
<Sample>
  <Item Name="Car">
    <Kinds>SUV</Kinds>
  <Item Name="Food">
    <Kinds>Pizza</Kinds>
  <Item Name="Fruit">
    <Kinds>Apple</Kinds> 
  <priceofgoods>
    <Item Name="SUV">
      <Price>1000000</Price>
    <Item Name="Pizza">
      <Price>15</Price>
    <Item Name="Apple">
      <Price>1</Price>    
  </price of goods>
</Sample>
```

I try to Make Class My Project
This is My Codes but It doesn't work the way I think.

```
  [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("Sample", IsNullable = true)]
    public sealed class SampleXml
    {
        [XmlElement("Item ")]
        public KindsofItem[] KindsofItems { get; set; }
        public PriceofKinds[] PriceofKind { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("Item", IsNullable = true)]
    public sealed class KindsofItem
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string ParamName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Kinds")]
        public int ParamKinds { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("priceofgoods", IsNullable = true)]
    public sealed class PriceofKinds
    {
        [XmlElement("Item")]
        public GoodsElements[] GoodsElement { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("Item", IsNullable = true)]
    public sealed class GoodsElements
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string ParamName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Price")]
        public int ParamPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you for letting me know what is wrong with creating a class.

Comment: Can you share the code which deserializes the xml to class object? `It doesn't work the way I think.` can you elaborate more ? the example XML you shared is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble creating different names of classes and properties, but using the defaults of `XmlSerializer` in this way maps everything in your XML. (Your XML was not correct, and I had to update it in this example and make some modifications). Hopefully this can get you set on the right track.

**XML**

```xml
<Sample>
  <Items>
    <Item Name="Car">
      <Kinds>SUV</Kinds>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Food">
      <Kinds>Pizza</Kinds>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Fruit">
      <Kinds>Apple</Kinds>
    </Item>
  </Items>
  <PriceOfGoods>
    <Good Name="SUV">
      <Price>1000000</Price>
    </Good>
    <Good Name="Pizza">
      <Price>15</Price>
    </Good>
    <Good Name="Apple">
      <Price>1</Price>
    </Good>
  </PriceOfGoods>
</Sample>
```

**C# code**

```cs
namespace xmltoserializable
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Sample));

            // Load xml from source
            Sample result;
            using (System.IO.Stream reader = new System.IO.FileStream(".\\data.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                // Deserialize xml into object
                result = (Sample)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Sample
    {
        public Item[] Items { get; set; }
        public Good[] PriceOfGoods { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Kinds { get; set; }
    }

    public class Good
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Zac, Thanks so much for your help I was able to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

**There is one issue in your XML**. you have Item node open but not closed e.g.

```
<Item Name="Car">
```

Correct format can be like

```
<Item Name="Car"/>
```

**OR**

```
<Item Name="Car"></Item>
```

Similar to what you can refer to in **Price** or **Kinds** node.

**There are a couple of issues in your Class**, I have corrected the class and put my comments inline there.

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Sample", IsNullable = true)]
public sealed class SampleXml
{
    [XmlElement("Item")] //remove space at the end of 'item' name
    public KindsofItem[] KindsofItems { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("priceofgoods")] //added element name 'priceofgoods'
    public PriceofKinds[] PriceofKind { get; set; }
}
[Serializable()]
//[XmlRoot("Item", IsNullable = true)] //Commented as not required
public sealed class KindsofItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Kinds")]
    public string ParamKinds { get; set; } //int to string, as you wanted to store string value e.g. SUV, Pizza, Apple
}
[Serializable()]
//[XmlRoot("priceofgoods", IsNullable = true)] --> //commented as not required
public sealed class PriceofKinds
{
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public GoodsElements[] GoodsElement { get; set; }
}
[Serializable()]
//[XmlRoot("Item", IsNullable = true)]
public sealed class GoodsElements
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string ParamName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Price")]
    public int ParamPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Now, this is a working line charm. you can create a sample and play with it using XmlSerializer.

//**Output**

```
<Sample>
  <Item Name="Fruit">
    <Kinds>Apple</Kinds>
  </Item>
  <Item Name="Food">
    <Kinds>Pizza</Kinds>
  </Item>
  <Item Name="Car">
    <Kinds>SUV</Kinds>
  </Item>
  <priceofgoods>
    <Item Name="SUV">
      <Price>1000000</Price>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Pizza">
      <Price>15</Price>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Apple">
      <Price>1</Price>
    </Item>
  </priceofgoods>
</Sample>
```

**Code to populate sample data to generate xml file**

```
SampleXml sampleXml = new SampleXml();

List<PriceofKinds> priceofKinds = new List<PriceofKinds>();
PriceofKinds priceofKind = new PriceofKinds();
List<GoodsElements> goodsElements = new List<GoodsElements>();
GoodsElements goodsElement = new GoodsElements();
goodsElement.ParamName = "SUV";
goodsElement.ParamPrice = 1000000;
goodsElements.Add(goodsElement);
goodsElement = new GoodsElements();
goodsElement.ParamName = "Pizza";
goodsElement.ParamPrice = 15;
goodsElements.Add(goodsElement);
goodsElement = new GoodsElements();
goodsElement.ParamName = "Apple";
goodsElement.ParamPrice = 1;
goodsElements.Add(goodsElement);
priceofKind.GoodsElement = goodsElements.ToArray();
priceofKinds.Add(priceofKind);

List<KindsofItem> kindsofItems = new List<KindsofItem>();
KindsofItem kindsofItem = new KindsofItem();
kindsofItem.ParamName = "Fruit";
kindsofItem.ParamKinds = "Apple";
kindsofItems.Add(kindsofItem);
kindsofItem = new KindsofItem();
kindsofItem.ParamName = "Food";
kindsofItem.ParamKinds = "Pizza";
kindsofItems.Add(kindsofItem);
kindsofItem = new KindsofItem();
kindsofItem.ParamName = "Car";
kindsofItem.ParamKinds = "SUV";
kindsofItems.Add(kindsofItem);
sampleXml.KindsofItems = kindsofItems.ToArray();
sampleXml.PriceofKind = priceofKinds.ToArray();
```

**Call to generate sample Serialization**

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(sampleXml.GetType());
using (TextWriter txtWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\SampleXml_01.xml"))
{ xs.Serialize(txtWriter, sampleXml); }
```